# Add commas to items and with "and" near the end in PHP

Tags: php, loops, csv

I want to add a comma to every item except the last one. The last one must have "and".

Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3

But items can be from 1 +

So if one item:

> Item 1

If two items:

> Item 1 and Item 2

If three items:

> Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3

If four items:

> Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 and Item 4

etc, etc.

Comment: Or, you could use an [oxford comma](http://www.thenation.com/sites/default/files/user/194836/OxfordComma.jpeg), which is equally correct (for a slightly different value of "correct").  :-)

Comment: How predictable is the formatting?  Obviously, you can'd just split items at every space character.  Are they all called /[Ii]tem [0-9]+/ ?  You wouldn't want "Item, 1, Item, 2, Item and 3".  So ... is our input a string, or an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here’s a function for that; just pass the array.

```
function make_list($items) {
    $count = count($items);

    if ($count === 0) {
        return '';
    }

    if ($count === 1) {
        return $items[0];
    }

    return implode(', ', array_slice($items, 0, -1)) . ' and ' . end($items);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/5JXcGi4N)

Answer (score 3):

minitech's solution on the outset is elegant, except for one small issue, his output will result in:

```
var_dump(makeList(array('a', 'b', 'c'))); //Outputs a, b and c
```

But the proper formatting of this list (up for debate) should be; a, b, and c. With his implementation the next to last attribute will never have ',' appended to it, because the array slice is treating it as the last element of the array, when it is passed to `implode()`.

Here is an implementation I had, and properly (again, up for debate) formats the list:

```
class Array_Package
{
    public static function toList(array $array, $conjunction = null)
    {
        if (is_null($conjunction)) {
            return implode(', ', $array);
        }

        $arrayCount = count($array);

        switch ($arrayCount) {

            case 1:
                return $array[0];
                break;

            case 2:
                return $array[0] . ' ' . $conjunction . ' ' . $array[1];
        }

        // 0-index array, so minus one from count to access the
        //  last element of the array directly, and prepend with
        //  conjunction
        $array[($arrayCount - 1)] = $conjunction . ' ' . end($array);

        // Now we can let implode naturally wrap elements with ','
        //  Space is important after the comma, so the list isn't scrunched up
        return implode(', ', $array);
    }
}

// You can make the following calls

// Minitech's function
var_dump(makeList(array('a', 'b', 'c'))); 
// string(10) "a, b and c"

var_dump(Array_Package::toList(array('a', 'b', 'c')));
// string(7) "a, b, c"

var_dump(Array_Package::toList(array('a', 'b', 'c'), 'and'));
string(11) "a, b, and c"

var_dump(Array_Package::toList(array('a', 'b', 'c'), 'or'));
string(10) "a, b, or c"
```

Nothing against the other solution, just wanted to raise this point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant that has an option to support the controversial [Oxford Comma](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_the_Oxford_comma.htm) and takes a parameter for the conjunction (and/or).  Note the extra check for two items; not even Oxford supporters use a comma in this case.

```
function conjoinList($items, $conjunction='and', $oxford=false) {
    $count = count($items);

    if ($count === 0){
        return '';
    } elseif ($count === 1){
        return $items[0];
    } elseif ($oxford && ($count === 2)){
        $oxford = false;
    }

    return implode(', ', array_slice($items, 0, -1)) . ($oxford? ', ': ' ') . $conjunction . ' ' . end($items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implode the X - 1 items with a comma and add the last one with "and".

Comment: For generality, what if there is only one item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$items = array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");

$item = glueItems($items);

function glueItems($items) {
    if (count($items) == 1) {
        $item = implode(", ", $items);
    } elseif (count($items) > 1)  {
        $last_item = array_pop($items);
        $item = implode(", ", $items) . ' and ' . $last_item;
    } else {
        $item = '';
    }
    return $item;
}
echo $item;
```

Comment: Why would there need to be an implode if there is only one item?

Answer (score 0):

My function, based on others here, that I feel like is more streamlined.  Also always adds in the Oxford comma because there really is no "controversy" or debate about whether it's correct or not to use.

```
//feed in an array of words to turn it into a written list.
//['bacon'] turn into just 'bacon'
//['bacon','eggs'] turns into 'bacon and eggs'
//['bacon','eggs','ham'] turns into 'bacon, eggs, and ham'
function writtenList($items) {

    //nothing, or not an array? be done with this
    if (!$items || !is_array($items)) return '';

    //list only one or two items long, this implosion should work fine
    if (count($items)<=2) {
        return implode(' and ',$items);
    //else take off the last item, implode the rest with just a comma and the remaining item
    } else {
        $last_item = array_pop($items);
        return implode(", ",$items).', and '.$last_item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well if it is an array just use `implode(...)`

Example:

```
$items = array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");
$items[count($items) - 1] = "and " . $items[count($items) - 1];
$items_string = implode(", ", $items);

echo $items_string;
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/k7xISG

Comment: This would not print out the requested "and" string before the last key.

Comment: Wrong concatenation operator too.

Comment: This still places an unwanted comma before the final item. OP example shows " and" in place of the comma.

Comment: @SimonMayer proper English has a comma **before** the AND

Comment: @SimonMayer http://www.thenation.com/sites/default/files/user/194836/OxfordComma.jpeg

Comment: @Neal: I think omitting the comma is acceptable now, and it is what the user wants. (And yes, I do use a comma before "and" too.)

Comment: Oxford comma but incorrectly prints and $items[0] for arrays with count 1